# Return correct 201 when using controller actions attribute routing

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

Net core 3 web api. It uses attribute routing for controllers actions. Few separate controllers with post methods (e.g. CreatedContract) should return 201 where routeName related to : GetOperationsById. Example is very simplified comparing to actual app, so please lets not put to much attention to it style

How to set route name to CreatedAtRoute correctly:

```
[ApiController]
public class OperationsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("contractsOperation/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetOperationsById(int id)
    {
        var operation = _service.GetOperation(id);
        return Ok(operation);
    }
}

[ApiController]
public class ContractsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("saveContract")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreatedContract(string jsonData)
    {
        var newlyCreatedContract = _service.Create(jsonData);

        //var route = this value should point out to OperationsController -> GetOperationsById

        return CreatedAtRoute(route, new { newlyCreatedContract.Id }, newlyCreatedContract);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to add a route name to the  GetOperationsById route attribute and then use this attribute name as the parameter to the CreatedAtRoute method.

More details, you could refer to below example:

Other controller method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("contractsOperation/{id}", Name = nameof(GetOperationsById))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetOperationsById(int id)
    {
      
        return Ok("aa");
    }
```

Call it:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {

        return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(FooController.GetOperationsById), new { id = 1 }, new { id=1});

    }
```

Result[image]: